# How to delete any array values from array on button click in each row

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, delete-row, buttonclick

I want to delete row as well as delete that value from array but I want delete button on each row and need to delete any index value on button click

How can I insert delete button on each row and delete row as well as value from same array ?

```js
var users = []

$(document).ready(loadTable);

function loadTable() {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < users[i].length; j++) {
      //console.log(users[i][j])
    } {
      continue;
    }

  }
}

$("#submit").on('click', function() {
  var temp = [document.getElementById("id").value, document.getElementById("name").value]
  users.push(temp)

  loadTable($("tbody").append("<tr>" +
    "<td>" + $("#id").val() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $("#name").val() + "</td>" +

    //"<td>"+<button href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF1 btn btn-small btn-danger">Remove</button>+"</td>"+

    "</tr>"));

  console.log(users)
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <button type="button" id="submit">Add</button>
  <table id="demo">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding a column in a table to add button and then add `onclick` event to delete the record.

**Demo :**

```js
var users = [];

$("#submit").on('click', function() {
  const id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var temp = [id, name]
  users.push(temp)

  $("tbody").append("<tr id='row" + id + "'>" +
                    "<td>" + id + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + name + "</td>" +
                    "<td><button onclick='deleteRecord(" + id + ")'>Remove</button></td>" +
                    "</tr>");
});

function deleteRecord(id) {
  document.querySelector('#row' + id).remove();
  const updatedArray = users.filter((user) => Number(user[0]) !== id);
  console.log(updatedArray);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="number" name="id" id="id">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <button type="button" id="submit">Add</button>
        <table id="demo">
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a remove button on each new line addition. Then add **`addEventListener`** "click" on the click button and **add a** `name` in it. The code added to the load table line will be like this

```
"<td>"+"<button class='remCF1 btn btn-small btn-danger'" + "onClick='delRow(" +idLastUser +")' name='delButton'>Delete</button></td>"
```

Then, add a function `delete` in your js file

```
function delRow(id){
   this.users.splice(id, 1);
   document.getElementById("row" + id).remove();
   updateRowId(id);
}
```

And create a function `update id`, to update the id in the `<tr>` and update the input to the `delRow` function in the `<button>`

```
function updateRowId(id) {
  let tabRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let buttonRows = document.getElementsByName("delButton");
  let updateNum = id;
  for (let i = id; i < tabRows.length; i++) {
     let updateRowId = tabRows[i].getAttribute("id");
     let updateDelRow = "delRow(" + updateNum + ")";
     buttonRows[i].setAttribute("onclick", updateDelRow);
     document.getElementById(updateRowId).id = "row" + updateNum;
     updateNum++;
  }
}
```

The overall code will be like this

```js
var users = [];
$(document).ready(loadTable);

function loadTable() {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < users[i].length; j++) {
      //console.log(users[i][j]);
    }
    {
      continue;
    }
  }
}

$("#submit").on("click", function () {
  var temp = [
    document.getElementById("id").value,
    document.getElementById("name").value
  ];
  users.push(temp);
  var idLastUser = users.length - 1;
  loadTable(
    $("tbody").append(
      "<tr id='row" + idLastUser +"'>" +
        "<td>" + $("#id").val() +"</td>" +
        "<td>" +$("#name").val() +"</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        "<button class='remCF1 btn btn-small btn-danger'" +
        "onClick='delRow(" + idLastUser + ")' name='delButton'>Delete</button></td>" +
        "</tr>"
    )
  );
  //console.log(users);
  //console.log(idLastUser);
});

function delRow(id) {
  //Remove an array in var of users that has an index of id selected
  this.users.splice(id, 1);
  //Remove row on table
  document.getElementById("row" + id).remove();
  //Update id on <tr> and parameter in <button> on delRow function
  updateRowId(id);
}

function updateRowId(id) {
  let tabRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let buttonRows = document.getElementsByName("delButton");
  let updateNum = id;
  for (let i = id; i < tabRows.length; i++) {
    let updateRowId = tabRows[i].getAttribute("id");
    let updateDelRow = "delRow(" + updateNum + ")";
    buttonRows[i].setAttribute("onclick", updateDelRow);
    document.getElementById(updateRowId).id = "row" + updateNum;
    updateNum++;
  }
  console.log(this.users);
  console.log(tabRows);
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="submit">Add</button>
<table id="demo">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think there might be a better and shorter way. But I haven't found it yet

[How to remove the table row in a table using JavaScript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-the-table-row-in-a-table-using-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20remove%28%29%20method%20is%20used%20to%20remove%20the,and%20events%20of%20the%20selected%20elements.%20Syntax%3A%20node.remove%28%29?msclkid=9f268538b18c11ec98d9af22a9bf91f9)

Comment: your past code is running properly. In this code only rows are deleting but not deleting values from row

Comment: I've updated my code, the code is running pretty well. But I think there is a shorter way than this. Hope you enjoy :)